# other expressions for "got it"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm looking for other expressions for "got it" as answer in a context where someone's explained something to me and I've come to understand it with the help of the explanation.

Comment: "I understand" would be the obvious one!

Comment: I often say "Understood." It's not grammatical, but for informal conversational use, it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/i-see#:%7E:text=You%20can%20say%20%27I%20see,%27%E2%80%94%27I%20see.),
You can say '*I see*' to indicate that you understand what someone is telling you.

A: He came home in my car.

B: I see.

Other synonyms: I understand, right, uh huh.